# how to include static library into another Project

Tags: iphone, ipad, static-libraries

I am using Xcode 4.2.1.

I do have a static library libSignatureLibrary.a  (which is 58k in memory)!

and I Created a new project SingleViewBased and open Link Binary With Libraries click '+' added libSignatureLibrary.a which is stored at desktop i added in the application.

I open Target Dependencies  Click '+'  i can't see the libSignatureLibrary.a library into my project!

I don't know where i did the mistake!

Can any one give me solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,just copy this libSignatureLibrary.a physically to your project folder and from there just add it your project.It will work.

Comment: Its Added into my project !  but not able to set into target Dependencies!  I can see that file which is in my application!

Comment: No just add along with the other files you add,it will automatically get there once you add in your project panel.

Comment: yeap! i added how the other file added into to project right click addfiletoSingleViewcontroller and i added the libSignatureLibrary.a

Comment: Yeah thats it,did you build and checked it?

Comment: Okay if it worked,then please accept the answer and vote it .. :)